# Today there is privacy.resistFingerprinting.letterbox which prevents Firefox/Tor from Leak the screen resolution of the computer

Tags: torproject.org

Is today resizing the tor window make it easier for governments to track Tor users?

When `privacy.resistFingerprinting.letterbox` is on, is it possible to resize the tor window to the maximum without the government/advertising site/Facebook/etc... being able to track me as a person seeking privacy?

**What is Letterbox?**

Letterbox is a feature that prevents a special resolution like: 1091x949 by adding empty space around the site to round the resolution to 1000x900 and thus prevents a user from making himself special. A resolution of 1091x949 is a very specific number and if a site sees that only one person uses this resolution then it will be easy follow him but if the resolution is 1000x900 then it will be more difficult to follow such a person with a thousand people who have the same resolution.

(in any case changing the resolution does not affect your connection to the site you will still be protected and no one can know who you are The browser is well built, YOU are the one who will cause yourself to leak information Like your first name or your IP address or even your email. If you change the resolution when Letterbox is running then in any case when you close the browser the resolution resets to the default settings so I can't figure out how exactly it will matter what the Browser size is if everyone starts Letterbox and opens the window Tor in full window so everyone will have the same resolution which makes tracking a Tor user a bit harder )

Am I right?

**The only reason I think that tor should not be increased to full window is the possibility of a site to identify, despite the letterbox, on which computer the browser is opened, because there is a difference in the resolution of a laptop and a desktop computer, and Windows is usually because Windows increases the size of applications and text on laptops so that laptop users will be comfortable use the laptop but it can be solved! Simply that Tor will oblige the laptop user to change the "Scale and layout" settings from 120% or any other number to 100% and that way sites will not be able to tell if the Tor user is using a laptop or a desktop computer

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to resize the tor window to the maximum without [THEM] being able to track me as a person seeking privacy?

There is no 100% guarantee if you resize to the maximum, nor if you don't resize at all.